# Can we hide a bottom bar in android

Tags: android, listview, onclicklistener

I want if I select even a single items from the list view bottom bar appears and if haven't selected any item bottom bar disappears.
[image]

Comment: You can make a listener for item of list-view to show/hide bottom bar.

Comment: Try to use android:visibility="gone" or android:visibility="visible" in your xml layout and In your listview click event set BottombarLayoutId.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); or BottombarLayoutId.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Comment: Your  "ADD" with increment button looks awesome. Can you give any lib for that or can you guide me to create that?

Answer (score 0):

```
something.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

or

```
something.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

GONE, removed from activity until you set it VISIBLE. INVISIBLE, take same place than before, but it is invisible.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private boolean isShowBottom = true;
    onCreate{
      listview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                if(isShowBottom){
                                  isShowBottom = false;
                                  bottmLayout.setvisibility(View.VISIBLE);}
                            }
                        });
    }
```

Comment: Here,no need to add condition.first screen display time do bottom layout gone.on click of list-view bottom layout make visible.

Answer (score 0):

Set your bottom bar visibility on list view click listener.

If you set

```
yourBottomBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

yourBottomBar is invisible, but it still takes up space for layout purposes.

And If you set

```
yourBottomBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

yourBottomBar is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for layout purposes.